# Swift 4 - Adding UITapGestureRecognizer to a subview image - the method is not called

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following `UITapGestureRecognizer` setup, but the method is not called?

Note: that the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is added to a subview item.

Also, it works when adding the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in `SUStepView` itself - only problem is that I need it in the container.

```
class StepViewContainer: NSObject, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
var view: SUStepView?

    @objc func tapAction(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    }

    override init(){
        super.init()
        // View
        self.view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SignupV3Views", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as? SUStepView

        let mytapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))
        mytapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.view?.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(mytapGestureRecognizer)            
    }
}
```

The view in StepViewContainer:

```
class SUStepView: UIView {
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @objc public func nextStepTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(nextStepTap))
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        self.imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width / 2
        self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true

}
```

Comment: why you are not used direct `imageView ` instead of `self.view?.imageView`

Comment: I have a container(self) that is handling different events.

Comment: did you set userInteractionEnabled = true on the imageView?

Comment: Good suggestion, but yes

Comment: I think I am missing this: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

Comment: Don't you have some other gestures in self? They could cover your gesture.    In this case otherGesture.require(toFail: tapGestureRecognizer) could help

Comment: Ok. Then maybe selector not called. Try #selector(YourControllerName.nextStepTap). Or imageView / self.view? is nil. I can't suggest any other reasons, sorry. Hope you will find the reason.

Answer (score 26):

**Swift 4 Code :**

**TapGesture :**

```
 tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.myviewTapped(_:)))
 tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
 tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
```

**ImageView Tap :**

```
    self.imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width/2.0, height: self.view.frame.size.height/2.0))
    self.imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width / 2
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    self.view.addSubview(self.imageView)
```

**Call On Tap**

```
@objc func myviewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if self.imageView.backgroundColor == UIColor.yellow {
        self.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }else{
        self.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }
}
```

Comment: Why I have to add `@objc` before the function?

Comment: Because in Swift 4, functions are no longer implicitly exposed to Objective-C code, which is needed to be able to invoke it as a selector.

Comment: Just setting `imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` did the trick for me

Answer (score 12):

try this.

```
let mytapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(myTapAction))
mytapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(mytapGestureRecognizer)
```

method.

```
@objc func myTapAction(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
}
```

Comment: @objc should added to the selector method

Comment: numberOfTapsRequired == 1 by default, actually